# If $(a-1) (b-2) (c-3) (d-4) = N$ , where $a, b, c, d$ are distinct natural numbers between 1 and 4 (both inclusive). Find the probability that N=0

Tags: probability

If $(a-1)(b-2)(c-3)(d-4) = N$ , where $a, b, c, d$ are distinct natural numbers between 1 and 4 (both inclusive). Find the probability that $N=0$

**My thought:**

Sample space would be all distinct values of $N = n(S)$

Favorable cases would be when $N=0 = 1/(n(s))$

I started listing my sample space, but its involving a lot of checking as I am manually putting all $24$ such combinations of $a, b, c, d$ possible and finding out my sample space,  am I doing right? and what would be an efficient way to solve this?

Comment: Instead of $4$ variables, consider the general case of $n$ variables. The number of configuration which make $N \ne 0$ is known as the $n^{th}$ [derrangment number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement) and denoted as $!n$. So the probability you seek is $1 - \frac{!4}{4!} = 1 - \frac{9}{24} = \frac58$. Look at above wiki entry for derivation of formula of $!n$.

Comment: Since there are only 4 factors, I suggest the direct approach, rather than Inclusion Exclusion.  Computing the opposite, after calculating the probability that $a \neq 1$, without loss of generality, $a=2$.  Then, you have two cases, depending on whether or not $b = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: How can $N = 0$? If and only if at least one of the factors is zero.

The best way to go about this is to compute the probability that $N \neq 0$. This can be done by first identifying the probability that $a \neq 1$, then the probability that $b \neq 2$ and $b \neq a$ (note that this is a place where double counting can happen if you're not careful!), and so on. Then use the fact that $P(N = 0) = 1 - P(N \neq 0)$.

Comment: It's the probability that the permuation $a,b,c,d$ of $1,2,3,4$ is not a derangement. There are well known expressions for the number of permutations and the number of derangements.

Comment: @ArthurVause I agree, but for someone asking this question is it really appropriate to invoke those formulas? I would assume this is a homework problem for which a more direct approach is needed